# Access path trough Command Promt

Tags: windows, command-line

Totally new to this.

*I have this task to do:
https://gist.github.com/bretcope/37bbcd1f4ac5297d0a5847863271b439*

*However I can only get to Step 5 as I run in to these Error-messages when I try different things:*

```
C:\Users\bsoev>C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools
'C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\bsoev>\Downloads\platform-tools
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\bsoev>Downloads\platform-tools
'Downloads\platform-tools' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

*Thank you for your time*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure that `C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools` exists on the system i.e. you have downloaded and extracted `platform-tools` in e.g. `C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads`.
2. None of your example commands are correct. You need to preface your path with [cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) (the "change directory" command), as noted in Step 5 of your link:

   > Open a terminal (Command Prompt on Windows) and navigate to the platform-tools directory
   >
   > e.g. cd C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\platform-tools

Comment: Anaksunaman, that helped a lot. 
However, now bullitt 6 is the problem. I get the following problem:

C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools>./adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.spage
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any idea?

Comment: I believe there may be a typo in the gist at Step 6. Assuming you have run `cd C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools` and are in the directory `C:\Users\bsoev\Downloads\platform-tools`, you should see an executable labeled `adb.exe`. In this case, prefacing the command with `./` is not only arguably incorrect (it would normally be .\ on Windows) but also unnecessary. You should just be able to run e.g. `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.spage`.

Comment: Note that `adb shell` should connect to whatever the default device detected is, but the phone needs to be recognized by `adb`. You should be able to run `adb devices -l` and see an entry for your phone if there is any question about this.